# Capturing Speed in background of app

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-gps

I want to capture speed on GPS in the background on a program.  I have the code to capture the speed, but it will not work unless it's the first thing running in the program.  Should this be coded as a Broadcast Intent, or an Intent Service in order to pop up a notification afterwards?

SpeedManagerService.java:

```
public class SpeedManagerService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "SpeedCheckerService";

private boolean isRunning = false;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i( TAG, "Service onCreate" );

    isRunning = true;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.i( TAG, "Service onStartCommand" );

    //Creating new thread for my service

    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            if (isRunning) {
                Log.i( TAG, "Service running" );
            }
        }

    } ).start();

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

And then I added the Intent for that particular page under the Splash page (to run under the onCreate method, right before the splash page begins):

```
 public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

Intent intent = new Intent( this, Checker.class );
    startService( intent );
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend posting some of the code for your speed capture or a representation of the configuration of your application; that way we can be of better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it seems like you can do all the work in Service. It will keep running all the time- you can run a separate thread for managing incoming data handling, register and unregister receivers at runtime and s0notify user as well. From my experience, it is a good idea to handle stream of values in reactove way (rx)- you receive data, pass it to chain of operators (filter by speed value) and process at the end. IntentService is better suited for long running one time job

Comment: Thanks, both answers help.  Hopefully I can get this sorted and started.  Appreciate the guidance!

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, I can add a class with an IntentService attached to it, so when the app starts, the service will start in the background and read the code that needs to read the speed and capture it, and then send a notification along with it? I will post some of the code.. if someone can help me with the service, I'd greatly appreciate it too..

Comment: Intent service run once ond the terminate (see docs) use ordinary Service, which will run indefinetely and make all procesding in it

Comment: I added some more code.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a Service and setup your conditions inside that. For starters, go through this [Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#BestPerformance). You can call the getSpeed() function in your Location Listener.